# Creating a New Draft of a Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Creating a New Draft of an interaction – Can the new draft of an interaction identify where the original(prior version) was stopped mid way and continue from there. I personally feel it's not possible however in case it is, how can we achieve this? The idea is not to repeat all the steps covered in the prior version and only cover the remaining journey hence excluding the customers all ready covered and targeting the remaining ones.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my previous answer. So this is how it behaves -

Let's say you deploy a journey and 100 contacts are injected into it. Now mid-way you decide to create a new draft.
In this case, those 100 people will stay in the previous version only and only the new ones will enter the newer version of the journey while those 100 will stay in the previous version till they exit the journey. Hope it helps.
You can read through the below documentation as well

[Journey Builder Interaction Versions](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/interaction_versions/)